# FATAL ERROR: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). My code won't run

Tags: c++, stack, exc-bad-access

When I run my program with predetermined inputs, I get the error message. What could be causing it and how can I fix it?

I don't know what to do. I've researched the topic on Google and none of the advice is specific enough to help.

```
void alpha_Array(){
        std::string nameArr[50];
        nameArr[0] = "Reddit";
        nameArr[1] = "Facebook";
        std::string passArr[50];
        passArr[0] = "1";
        passArr[1] = "2";
        std::stack<std::string> organiser;
        std::stack<std::string> passwordStack;
        int loops = 1;
        organiser.push(nameArr[0]);
        passwordStack.push(passArr[0]);
        for(int x = 1; x < 50; x++){
            loops++;
            std::string best = organiser.top();
            std::string bestPass = passwordStack.top();
            std::string newStr = nameArr[x];
            std::string newPass = passArr[x];
            if (nameArr[x].empty()){
                break;
            }
            std::string tipTop = alpha_Compare(best, newStr, 0);
            if (tipTop == best){
                organiser.pop();
                organiser.push(newStr);
                organiser.push(best);
                passwordStack.pop();
                passwordStack.push(newPass);
                passwordStack.push(bestPass);
            }
            else{
                organiser.push(newStr);
                passwordStack.push(newPass);
            }

        }
        for (int x = 0; x < loops; x++){
            std::string name = organiser.top();
            organiser.pop();
            std::string password = passwordStack.top();
            passwordStack.pop();
            std::cout<<"Name: "<<name<<std::endl<<"Password: "<<password<<std::endl<<std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I am expecting there to be a formatted response, such as:

Name: Facebook
Password: 1

Name: Reddit
Password: 2

But instead I get:

Name: Reddit
Password: 1

Name: Facebook
Password: 2

(lldb)

And the error at the end.

Comment: You have the same index 0 in to consecutive assignments `nameArr[0] = "Reddit";
nameArr[0] = "Facebook";`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I've edited it but still returns the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the loop value would become 3 after two iterations.

```
int loops = 1;
for(int x = 1; x < 50; x++){
    loops++;
    //...
}
```

Now in this part of the code you iterate 3 times:

```
for (int x = 0; x < loops; x++) {
    std::string name = organiser.top();
    organiser.pop();
    //...
}
```

So you pop the stack 3 times while there are only 2 elements.